# Envio de e-mails em massa - PHPMailer

Tags: php, envio-de-email, cron, newsletter

Bom dia!

Possuo um sistema de e-mail marketing e estou tendo problemas ao realizar um disparo de newsletter para uma lista grande de contatos. (Entendam lista grande como: uma lista contendo acima de 1000 e-mails).

Se eu realizar o disparo para uma quantidade inferior a 1000 emails, o disparo acontece perfeitamente. Se houver mais de 1000, ele não envia para todos, chegando a enviar até apenas para metade da lista.

Contatei a Localweb, servidor que hospeda minhas contas e por onde autentico o SMTP, e eles me informaram que pode ser uma possível perda de pacotes durante o envio.

Meu código busca no banco de dados (SQL Server) dentro de um laço *for* todos os e-mails da lista que foi selecionada pro disparo e aí realiza o envio. Uma consideração: o envio é realizado por um Cron Job que roda de 5 em 5 minutos.

Alguém pode me ajudar? Alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Meu código de envio:

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->setLanguage('br');
    $mail->CharSet='utf-8';   
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->Host = "xxx";
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'xxx';
    $mail->Password = 'xxx';
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
    $mail->Port = 587; 
    $mail->From = $email; (variável que vem do banco de dados)
    $mail->FromName = $fantasia; (variável que vem do banco de dados)
    $mail->SMTPOptions = array(
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false,
            'allow_self_signed' => true
        )
    );

    for($z=0; $z<count($bcc); $z++){

        if($html == '1'){
            $topo = recebe um código html específico;
              $rodape = recebe um código html específico;
              $texto2 = recebe um código html específico, concatenando as variáveis $topo e $rodape - newsletter que será enviada; 
        }else{
            if($topo == '1'){
              $topo = recebe um código html específico;
              $rodape = recebe um código html específico;
            }else{
                $topo = recebe um código html específico;
              $rodape = recebe um código html específico;
            }

            $texto2 = recebe o código html específico, concatenando $topo e $rodape - newsletter que será enviada; 
        }

        $mail->AddAddress($bcc[$z]['Email']);
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->Subject  = $tit; (variável vinda do banco)
        $mail->Body = $texto2;
        $mail->AltBody = $texto2;
        $enviado = $mail->Send();
        $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $mail->ClearAttachments();

    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O script pode esta terminando o processo antes da hora, tente utilizar o comando:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.set-time-limit.php

Ele define o tempo que o script vai rodar, quando você define o tempo para 0, este tempo fica ilimitado.

Ele pode esta sendo finalizado também por consumir muito processamento, tente colocar um tempo entre 100 e 100 e-mail por exemplo utilizando o sleep.

```
sleep(10);
```

Este tempo é em segundos

Comment: Mas... Por exemplo: tenho uma lista com 9000 contatos e meu script dispara para apenas 7000... Só que não há uma ordem, ele não segue a ordem que vem do banco, ele "escolhe" alguns e-mails e envia. Faz sentido? E o uso do ini_set('max_execution_time', time) é uma boa?

Comment: Da pra fazer algo mais simples, como por exemplo nos múltiplos de 100 ele  faz a espera if (0 == ($z % 100)){ sleep(10) ; }

Answer (score 0):

Creio que seja uma limitação da própria hospedagem. Normalmente é utilizado um serviço de terceiro para este tipo de envio, tais como: mailgun, mailchimp entre outros. Eles possuem uma API bem fácil de integrar e possuem planos gratuitos.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Você sabe algo sobre essa "perda de pacotes" ou se o PHPMailer tem um limite? Porque ele simplesmente pula alguns e-mails e envia pra outros.

Comment: Ele te retorna algum erro? Segue um link da github do PHPMailer falando sobre envio para listas: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists

Comment: Não... Erro algum :( Ele simplesmente não envia... E como eu falei ali em cima, se eu tiver uma lista pra 9000 contatos, às vezes ele chega a disparar só pra 4000. Eu vi sobre essa doc do PHPMailer e sigo essas instruções pra otimização, mas não sei o que pode estar acontecendo :(

Comment: Uma dúvida, ele ta pulando envio ou para em um determinado momento?

Comment: Ele pula envios, alguns ele chega a disparar assim salteando e outros pontos da lista, 50/100 emails seguidos, ele já nem dispara. Faz sentido?

Answer (score -2):

Certamente seu CRON de 5min não é suficiente para enviar todos estes emails. Já que PHPMailer é como se fosse um Curl. Para cada envio ele estabelece uma conexão com o servidor, autenticando e processando um de cada vez.